# ViewerJS First page of PDF is rendering upside down on Firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm using https://viewerjs.org/ to render a pdf viewer in a modal on my project.  The code is straight forward, and works on safari and chrome, but the first page is rendering upside down on firefox.

Hope someone's run into this before and can help out.

I'm placing this code within a modal:

```
<iframe src = "/ViewerJS/#../demo/ohm2013.pdf" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not at knowlege of the *ViewerJS*, but a quick dirty solution would be to **flip** the `iframe` with simple CSS

```
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```